# Dynamically Error messages in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have x custom object it having the fields quantity,qunatity increment i have to display Dynamic error message at the quantity field..
when MOD(Quantity__c, QtyIncrement__c )>0 this condition is achieved i have to display the error message dynamically in visualforce page,
Quantityincremnt is the inputHidden feild in visualforce page

For eample in Quantiyincrement=10, at that time if i enter quantity=2 at that it have to show error multiples of 10,
For eample in Quantiyincrement=2, at that time if i enter quantity=3 at that it have to show error multiples of 2,

Comment: Sathya what is your question specifically ? -did you already try something yourself ?

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke i can't understand how to solve this task.when i use validation rules at that time it showing static message.

Comment: Are you working with a page on a standard or custom controller?

Comment: @SimonLawrence i am using visualforce page with standard controller

Comment: then can I recommend you put an extension on the page with a method much like in my answer below?

Comment: any feedback on that at all?

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with a custom controller extension and visualforce page, which your question suggests you are, you can deploy something similar to the below to achieve onpage error messages with almost any dynamic value you wish..

The "description" of the process is in the comments of the snippets.

Sample page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Test_Object__c" extensions="testObjectExtension">

<!-- The error message block -->
<apex:pageMessages />

<apex:form>

    <!-- Our save button -->
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <!-- The two input fields in my example, the first must be smaller than the second -->
        <apex:inputField value="{!Test_Object__c.number1__c}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Test_Object__c.number2__c}" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Controller extension:

```
public class testObjectExtension {

    Test_Object__c toc {get; set;}

    // constructor, grab record
    public testObjectExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        toc = (Test_Object__c)controller.getRecord();
    }

    // Save method override
    public pageReference save()
    {
        // compare values - do what you like here regarding your two fields
        if(toc.number1__c < toc.number2__c)
        {
            // Add a custom error message to the page >>> THIS IS THE MAGIC LINE!
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new  ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Number 1 must be smaller than ' + toc.Number2__c);
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
            return null;
        }

        // otherwise save as usual
        upsert toc;

        return null;
    }    

}
```

.

.

This gives me a (fairly sparse) page that when incorrectly completed displays this message:

[image: error message]

Comment: I span this up in a developer edition, and I can confirm what I have put is exactly right for the above result. The obvious mistake being that I have said the number 1 must be SMALLER than number 2 (as per the error message) but my validating logic actually checks it the other way around! (that was a test)